# How to break this long radical into multiple lines?

Tags: math-mode, line-breaking

I've got a very long radical in a display-math environment, so long that the equation spills in the right margin. How can I break that equation over multiple lines, so that it doesn't go into the right margin?

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\[
    V_{DABC}=\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot DA \cdot DB \cdot DC \cdot \sqrt{1+2\cdot
    \cos \widehat{ADB}\cdot \cos \widehat{BDC}\cdot \cos \widehat{ADC}
    -\cos^2 \widehat{ADB} -\cos^2 \widehat{ADC} -\cos^2 \widehat{BDC}} 
    =\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}.
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first suggestion is to use `\alpha`, `\beta` and so on instead of naming angles by points.

Comment: How about using `)^{1/2}` instead of a root? would be easier to split up.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd much prefer Jubobs's approach, but just to show another method, you can split into two lines the radicand:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\[
  V_{DABC}=\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot DA \cdot DB \cdot DC \cdot
  \sqrt{
    \begin{aligned}
     1+&2\cos\widehat{ADB}\cos\widehat{BDC}\cos\widehat{ADC} \\
     & -\cos^2 \widehat{ADB} -\cos^2 \widehat{ADC} -\cos^2 \widehat{BDC}
    \end{aligned}
  }
  =\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}.
\]
\end{document}
```

I removed the unnecessary centered dots.

[image]

Comment: To avoid the (minimal) manual adjustment, one could use `multlined` environment from `mathtools`.

Comment: @Manuel Yes, that's a possibility.

Comment: Inasmuch as I like the other answers that provide simpler equations for clarity's sake, +1 for actually answering the question.

Answer (score 10):

As suggested by egreg in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163084/how-to-break-this-long-radical-into-multiple-lines/163088#comment373881_163084), the angles take up a lot of horizontal space, which you can claim back by defining shorter variables for them (alpha, beta, gamma, in my code).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} % <---- for \triangleq
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,showframe]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  V_{DABC} &=\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot DA \cdot DB \cdot DC \cdot
    \sqrt{
      1 + 2 \cos\alpha \cos\beta \cos\gamma
        -\cos^2 \alpha -\cos^2 \beta -\cos^2 \gamma
    } \\
           &= \dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\,,
\end{align*}
%
where \(\alpha \triangleq \widehat{BDC}\),
\(\beta \triangleq \widehat{ADC}\),
and \(\gamma \triangleq \widehat{ADB}\).
\end{document}
```

Comment: I find `\triangleq` ugly and unnecessary.

Comment: @egreg Personally, I find `\triangleq` useful to distinguish between an equality between two quantities that have already been introduced, and a definition, i.e. "we introduce the LHS and define it as equal to the RHS". I guess it's a matter of personal opinion. I'm curious... Do you use another symbol? Or do you not make that distinction?

Comment: I find that `=` is sufficient. Mathematicians have gone through without `:=` or similar symbols for centuries. Saying “where A=B” is usually clear; one can say “where we set A=B” if greater clarity seems needed.

Comment: Even more, you could omit `\cdot` between cosines. In my opinion `2 \cos \gamma \cos \alpha \cos \beta` is absolutely readable.

Comment: @Manuel You're right. See my edit.

Comment: I'd use  \equiv to define something. so \(\alpha \equiv \widehat{BDC}\)

Comment: @Nasser *I* wouldn't but thanks for the suggestion `:)`

Answer (score 8):

An approach that produces a result that's very similar to the one in @egreg's answer relies on the `\splitfrac` macro of the `mathtools` package.

In the example below, I also utilize a macro called `\V` that typesets its argument in text italics instead of math italics. The macro is applied to the strings "DABC", "ADB", "DA", etc to keep TeX from typesetting them as if they were separate variables named "A", "B", "C", etc.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for \splitfrac macro
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[hmargin=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,showframe]{geometry} 
\newcommand{\V}[1]{\textit{#1}} % shorthand macro, typesets its argument in text italics
\begin{document}
\[
V_{\V{DABC}}
=\frac{1}{6}\, \V{DA} \cdot \V{DB} \cdot \V{DC} \cdot
\sqrt{\splitfrac{
1+2\cos \widehat{\V{ADB}} \cdot \cos \widehat{\V{BDC}} \cdot \cos \widehat{\V{ADC}}}{
-\cos^2 \widehat{\V{ADB}} -\cos^2 \widehat{\V{ADC}}  -\cos^2 \widehat{\V{BDC}}}\,} 
=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}\,.
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think this is one of those cases where a local definition may help; in the code below, I have introduced `f(A,B,C,D)` under your radical, and then defined it immediately below.

[image: screenshot]

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    V_{DABC} & =\dfrac{1}{6}\cdot DA \cdot DB \cdot DC \cdot \sqrt{f(A,B,C,D)} \\
             & =\dfrac{2\sqrt{2}}{3}.
\end{align}
where
\begin{align*}
    f(A,B,C,D)  = 1 & +2\cdot \cos \widehat{ADB}\cdot \cos \widehat{BDC}\cdot \cos \widehat{ADC} \\
                    & -\cos^2 \widehat{ADB}-\cos^2 \widehat{ADC}-\cos^2 \widehat{BDC}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```