# Is there a programming language/API like documentation for common LaTeX packages (like amsmath)?

Tags: documentation

I just tried to figure out limitations (in a very abstract manner of the `\sqrt` makro in math package of LaTeX. Even after reading http://bay.uchicago.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf it appears poorly documented (so poorly that I don't believe that so many production focused people use it without every having complain and/or improved it). How would I figure out from a technical absract documentation (not that sort of common example soaked package documentations) whether e.g. `\sqrt` can be broken over multiple lines? There has to be links to available containing environments, etc.

Comment: `texdoc amsmath` returns (a local copy of) the user guide you link to. Perhaps you would prefer `texdoc amsmath.pdf` which returns a fully typeset document source of the package

Comment: for most latex packages `texdoc _package_name_` will show the full source documentation, for some (notably amsmath and graphics) texdoc will by default return a more user oriented user guide, but the full documentation is always available.

Comment: to obtain a list of *all* recognized documentation related to a particular package, `texdoc -l pkgname` will return a list from which you can select the particular instance you want to look at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, `texdef -t latex sqrt` returns:

> ```
> \long macro:->\@ifnextchar [\@sqrt \sqrtsign
> ```

This brings us to `\sqrtsign` (since we assume the optional argument is not present) and `texdef -t latex sqrtsign` returns:

> ```
> \macro:->\radical "270370\relax
> ```

So you either open The TeXbook or go to [the reference manual](http://www.tug.org/utilities/plain/cseq.html#radical-rp), where two keywords: *rule* and *subformula* tell you that the thing is unbreakable. Or you [search this site for `sqrt break`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=sqrt+break) and one of the results is [How to break this long radical into multiple lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163084/how-to-break-this-long-radical-into-multiple-lines) which clearly shows that `\sqrt` construct is unbreakable.

Once you know the TeX programming layer, you can decode any definition and see what's inside. Or you just look for other sources. (As a side note, I don't see how breaking an `\sqrt` over multiple lines can even come up to someone's mind.)

Comment: Thanks for that answer which fits very well to my question! To your side node: Imagine you want to stress precedences of operation, you'd want to write a long term under the root and then the simplication of that term and then extract the root, e.g. in `\sqrt{1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+8394238947923874} = \sqrt{8394238947923964} = 6\cdot sqrt(233173304108999)` you might want to break the first term.

Comment: @KarlRichter **Nobody** will understand your broken sqrt notation. Just use `(1+2+..........)^{1/2}`, which can be broken into multiple lines without any problem and it wouldn't cause any trouble.