# How continue an equation next line

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, two-column

How can continue the equation of the rectangle red in next line?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}

...

\begin{equation*}
    \left| \dot{r} \right| =
    \sqrt{{- \, {e}^{-t} \left( \cos t + \sin t \right)}^{2} \, + \, {{e}^{-t} \left( \cos t + \sin t \right)}^{2} \, + \, {(- \, {e}^{-t})}^{2}}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]

Comment: I would suggest to break the equation manually to control the output using an `aligned` environment and, the symbol `&` and ```\\```. Have a look [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Aligning_equations_with_amsmath)

Comment: @nikjohn hi, i already tried, problem is the root square.

Comment: why not using something like the `alignat*` from `mathtools` (or `amsmath`) package?

Comment: @Luis If breaking the two-column format just for this equation is not something you would like, you could have a look [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163084/how-to-break-this-long-radical-into-multiple-lines) as to how to break the square root into multiple lines and still look good

Comment: Do you know `breqn`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using the `multlined` environment from `mathtools` to break  the radicand . You also can choose not to break it, but to type in medsize (~80 % of \displaystyle) with the `\mediummath` command from `nccmath`. I took the opportunity to clean your code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \bigl| \dot{r} \bigr| =
    \sqrt{\begin{multlined}[b] -\!\bigl(e^{-t} ( \cos t + \sin t )\bigr)^2 + \\ \bigl(e^{-t} (\cos t + \sin t)\bigr)^2 + \bigl(-e^{-t}\bigr)^2 \end{multlined}}
\end{equation*}
\begin{align*}
    \bigl| \dot{r} \bigr| & =
    \sqrt{\medmath{ -\!\bigl(e^{-t} ( \cos t + \sin t )\bigr)^2 + \bigl(e^{-t} (\cos t + \sin t)\bigr)^2 + \bigl(-e^{-t}\bigr)^2}} \\
         & = \sqrt{ -\!\bigl(e^{-t} ( \cos t + \sin t )\bigr)^2 + \bigl(e^{-t} (\cos t + \sin t)\bigr)^2 + \bigl(-e^{-t}\bigr)^2}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was suggesting (about the first part of your answer)!

Comment: Great minds think together!

Comment: Are you sure the entire term `e^{-t}(\cos t + \sin t)` should be squared? The OP's code seems to suggest that only  `(\cos t + \sin t)` should be squared. (Of course, the OP's code might be in error...)

Comment: @Mico: Not sure at all. That's the way I interpreted all those spurious  `{ … }`. Anyway, it's only a demo.

Answer (score 6):

As the `equation*` environment doesn't permit line breaks, consider using a `multline*` environment. And, instead of creating a multi-line surd expression with a `\sqrt` instruction, I suggest you use `(...)^{1/2}` notation.

Two additional comments about your code: Do try to use `\left` and `\right` less frequently, and don't needlessly encase various terms in curly braces.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'multline*' env.
\begin{document}
...
\hrule % just to illustrate column width
\begin{multline*}
    | \dot{r} | = \bigl\{
    - e^{-t} ( \cos t + \sin t )^{2} \\
    + e^{-t} ( \cos t + \sin t )^{2}
    + (-e^{-t})^{2} \bigr\}^{1/2}
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are interested in a square root expression and not a power notation that Mico's answer provides, have a look at the following code:

```
\begin{equation*}
    \left| \dot{r} \right| =
    \sqrt{
        \begin{aligned}
        &{- \, {e}^{-t} \left( \cos t + \sin t \right)}^{2} \, + \, \\ 
        &{{e}^{-t}  \left( \cos t + \sin t \right)}^{2} \, + \, {(- \, {e}^{-t})}^{2}
        \end{aligned}   
        }
\end{equation*}
```

### Ouptut

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you could enhance readability by adding a `\quad` at the beginning of the second line.  **Edit:** Also note that the `mathtools` package provides a `multlined` environment (maybe you already knew… :-)

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti - I was not aware of that option since I do not usually encounter problems like this. It was a very helpful comment indeed

Comment: Thanks for all your answers, apparently the root squared be cant to break.

Comment: @nikjohn Off-topic, but seems that the surd is not perfectly connected to the line in the "Ouptut." Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this situation today and the simplest solution is to use {align*} within the equation environment and double back slash `\\` command at the location you want to start the next line. Although not automatic, it looks neat.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{align*}
            \Pi( \phi,\eta)= \int_0^L \left[ N \cdot \Lambda^T \left( \frac{d \eta_0}{ds} - \theta \times \frac{d \phi_0}{ds} \right)+M \cdot \Lambda^T \frac{d \theta}{ds} \right]ds \\
        -\int_0^L \left( \bar{n} \cdot \eta_0 + \bar{m} \cdot \theta \right) ds = 0
\end{align*}
\end{equation}
```