# \sqrt too long for one line

Tags: equations, sqrt

I have a very long SQRT() equation, that doesn't fit in a line. I couldn't simplify  it, since it involves terms in addition. Is there an alternative way to represent a root as 'SQRT{some function}' ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \Delta\sigma_{V,ij} = \sqrt{\Delta\sigma_{x,ij}^2 + \Delta\sigma_{y,ij}^2 + \Delta\sigma_{z,ij}^2 - (\Delta\sigma_{x,ij}\cdot\Delta\sigma_{y,ij} + \Delta\sigma_{y,ij}\cdot\Delta\sigma_{z,ij} + \Delta\sigma_{z,ij}\cdot\Delta\sigma_{x,ij}) + 3 \cdot (\Delta\tau_{xy,ij}^2 + \Delta\tau_{yz,ij}^2 + \Delta\tau_{zx,ij}^2)}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: As written, this doesn't sound like a TeX question but one of notation. I could generally get away with saying "$y=\sqrt f(x)$ where $f(x)=...$", but I don't know if you could.

Comment: I edited the title to be more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For details, see [How continue a equation next line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364116/).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
    \Delta\sigma_{V,ij} = \sqrt{\Delta\sigma_{x,ij}^2 + \Delta\sigma_{y,ij}^2 + \Delta\sigma_{z,ij}^2 - (\Delta\sigma_{x,ij}\cdot\Delta\sigma_{y,ij} + \Delta\sigma_{y,ij}\cdot\Delta\sigma_{z,ij} + \Delta\sigma_{z,ij}\cdot\Delta\sigma_{x,ij}) + 3 \cdot (\Delta\tau_{xy,ij}^2 + \Delta\tau_{yz,ij}^2 + \Delta\tau_{zx,ij}^2)}
\end{equation*}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364116/
\begin{equation*}
    \Delta\sigma_{V,ij} =
    \sqrt{\begin{multlined}[b] 
    \Delta\sigma_{x,ij}^2 + \Delta\sigma_{y,ij}^2 + \Delta\sigma_{z,ij}^2 - \\
    (\Delta\sigma_{x,ij}\cdot\Delta\sigma_{y,ij} + \Delta\sigma_{y,ij}\cdot\Delta\sigma_{z,ij} + \Delta\sigma_{z,ij}\cdot\Delta\sigma_{x,ij}) + \\ 
    3 \cdot (\Delta\tau_{xy,ij}^2 + \Delta\tau_{yz,ij}^2 + \Delta\tau_{zx,ij}^2)
    \end{multlined}}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I'd remove the square root sign altogether:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\Diff}{\mathop{}\!\Delta}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\Diff\sigma_{V,ij} =\Bigl(
&  \Diff\sigma_{x,ij}^2 + \Diff\sigma_{y,ij}^2 + \Diff\sigma_{z,ij}^2 \\
&- \bigl(\Diff\sigma_{x,ij}\Diff\sigma_{y,ij} +
    \Diff\sigma_{y,ij}\Diff\sigma_{z,ij} +
    \Diff\sigma_{z,ij}\Diff\sigma_{x,ij}\bigr) \\
&+ 3\bigl(\Diff\tau_{xy,ij}^2 + \Diff\tau_{yz,ij}^2 + \Diff\tau_{zx,ij}^2\bigr)
\Bigr)^{\!1/2}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\bigl(\Diff\sigma_{V,ij})^2 
={}& \Diff\sigma_{x,ij}^2 + \Diff\sigma_{y,ij}^2 + \Diff\sigma_{z,ij}^2 \\
&- \bigl(\Diff\sigma_{x,ij}\Diff\sigma_{y,ij} +
    \Diff\sigma_{y,ij}\Diff\sigma_{z,ij} +
    \Diff\sigma_{z,ij}\Diff\sigma_{x,ij}\bigr) \\
&+ 3\bigl(\Diff\tau_{xy,ij}^2 + \Diff\tau_{yz,ij}^2 + \Diff\tau_{zx,ij}^2\bigr)
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

With `\Diff` you need no `\cdot`, as the spacing will suffice.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I  propose to split the square root symbol over two lines with a hack, in two variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{dashrule} 

\begin{document}

\begin{fleqn}[1em]
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\\[-1ex]
   & Δ\sigma_{V,ij} = \\
    &\begin{multlined}[0.9\linewidth]
    √{Δ\sigma_{x,ij}² + Δ\sigma_{y,ij}² + Δ\sigma_{z,ij}² - (Δ\sigma_{x,ij} · \Delta\sigma_{y,ij} + Δ\sigma_{y,ij} · \Delta\sigma_{z,ij} + Δ\sigma_{z,ij} · \Delta\sigma_{x,ij})} \\[0.5ex]
     \overline{\rule{0pt}{2.4ex}+ 3 · (Δ\tau_{xy,ij}² + Δ\tau_{yz,ij}² + Δ\tau_{zx,ij}²)}
    \end{multlined}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\\[-1ex]
   & Δ\sigma_{V,ij} = \\
    &\begin{multlined}[0.9\linewidth]
    √{Δ\sigma_{x,ij}² + Δ\sigma_{y,ij}² + Δ\sigma_{z,ij}² - (Δ\sigma_{x,ij} · \Delta\sigma_{y,ij} + Δ\sigma_{y,ij} · \Delta\sigma_{z,ij} + Δ\sigma_{z,ij} · \Delta\sigma_{x,ij})}\hdashrule[2.66ex]{1.8em}{0.4pt}{2pt} \\[0.5ex]
     {\hdashrule[2.67ex]{1.8em}{0.4pt}{2pt}}\mkern -4mu\overline{\rule{0pt}{2.4ex}+ 3 · (Δ\tau_{xy,ij}² + Δ\tau_{yz,ij}² + Δ\tau_{zx,ij}²)}
    \end{multlined}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: `\overline`-magic :)

Comment: but would a reader understand this? (I am not sure I would have understood this without the context  of the question to say what the argument of the sqrt is)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I think it's self-explaining, as long as it does not interfere  with notations like complex conjugation. That's the way I used from high school with paper and pencil when necessary, so I thought it rather natural. We also might add dots at the end of the square root symbol and before the overline.

Comment: I would like to propose the use of `\surd` and also provide a vertically extensible version for use in displayed maths.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Following the lines sketched in my previous comment, I've added a variant which hopefully would be clearer to readers.